# How: Python Script to execute Terminal Command every hour?

Tags: python, swagger-ui

I'm trying to repeatedly execute a curl command with a python script, is there a better way to do such a task?

Comment: What is your Operating System? Environment? Please provide more details

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Im Using Mac OS, and Atom as my Editor.
Well, I havn't tried that much. I've never used Python before. That's what I have:
import os

os.system ("curl -X GET "https://someLinkWithApiKey" -H "accept: application/xml"")

Comment: If the point is to call curl you don't even need python at all, just use a shell script. For the "every hour" part, cf swapnil shashank's answer  - don't reinvent the squared wheel, use standard system tools.

Comment: thanks! As I said, i've never worked with used scripts and I need it as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below findings can help you in  linux environment.

You can do that with the help of a cron jab.

Steps to setup a cron job:

1. Open crontab by the command "crontab -e" on the shell
2. Paste the following in the file and correct the path
   0 * * * * /home/sshashank/script.py
3. Make sure you have given proper permissions to the folders where python script is going to run, folder where it is going to access(files/logs).
4. Please provide absolute path and not relative path.